# JSX loop not rendering

Tags: reactjs, loops, rendering, babeljs

I think I'm misunderstanding JSX. I've this piece of code:

```
const DgtPortal = ({children}) => {  
    console.log(children);
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      children,
      document.getElementById(children.props.id)
    );
  };

 render() {
    var customDgt = document.getElementsByClassName('cust-dgt');
    customDgt = Array.from(customDgt);
    var index = 1;
    var state = this.state;
    return  (
        <div>           
            <DgtPortal>               
                    <CustomDigital        
                    id={customDgt[index].id}   
                    icon={customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-icon')}
                    value={state.data[customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-bind')][customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-address')]}
                    />
            </DgtPortal>

            {customDgt.map(function(dgt, index){                
                <div>{console.log("child id = " + customDgt[index].id)}
                <DgtPortal>
                    <CustomDigital        
                    id={customDgt[index].id}   
                    icon={customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-icon')}
                    value={state.data[customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-bind')][customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-address')]}
                    />
                </DgtPortal></div>
                })                
            }

    </div>
    );
}
```

the DgtPortal inside the loop doesn't render nothing
while the one outside is rendering
I'm sure that the loop is executed  becuase of the log...
where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly `return` your`jsx`

```
        {customDgt.map(function(dgt, index){                
            return(<div>{console.log("child id = " + customDgt[index].id)}
            <DgtPortal>
                <CustomDigital        
                id={customDgt[index].id}   
                icon={customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-icon')}
                value={state.data[customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-bind')][customDgt[index].getAttribute('data-address')]}
                />
            </DgtPortal></div>)
            })                
        }
```